# The name "Alicia Han" appears to be calling!

Tags: missed-calls, htc-sensation-xe

I think there's a bug in Android where some *Alicia Han* appears to be calling. This happens *some times* if you hang up on someone calling you, or you have a missed call. The name appears in the instant before the correct name of the caller appears on the phone. To be specific: In the interim between the phone screen turns on and the content is loaded on the screen.

All relevant hits I get on the subject is [this tweet.](https://twitter.com/OriginBroadband/statuses/223425303194779649) So I'm not crazy!

Have any of you seen this, and do you know what happens / who Alicia Han is? 
This has happened haphazardly since I got my HTC Sensation XE a year ago.

Edit: I think the problem might be that there is a standard Label text for a Person entry (such as the ones in the Persons list) that is set to 'Alicia Han' and the label text is replaced when the Person information is fully loaded.

Edit: The `bug` is reproducible (at least for me) by hanging up an incoming call. The name Alicia Han appears for a few milliseconds before the real name is loaded.

Comment: The tweeter in your question confirmed that it was on Sense. Found 2 other persons on Sense too with this problem. I contacted the htc dev team. I'm awaiting an answer now.

Comment: @HenningKlevjer Got some response from htcdev, they are completely avoiding my question and offer a free 'repair' of my phone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138171/discussion-on-question-by-henning-klevjer-the-name-alicia-han-appears-to-be-ca).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for the answer to this question since I read it a year ago. I searched several times and I always find the same question in many forums, but no answers. The only certainty is that it is not a bug of Android as such because it only happens for users of the HTC brand, but I've never found anything productive that comes out of HTC staff in this regard. This question was asked over a year ago and still there is no answer, so I'd like to be the first to give an answer, even if it is a guess.

What I can conclude from the comments on this and other forums is that "Alicia Han" is a placeholder for contact name which the HTC developers put to be replaced for real contact data when you receive a call (in the same way this placeholder could be *"John Doe"* in English or "Fulano de Tal" in Spanish), although it seems feasible according to the comment of @qdoe (being HTC a Chinese corporation), I don't know how random can be [that choice of name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_names_in_different_languages#Chinese), it could be even a co-worker's name as suggesteded by @Propeller, or maybe it is only to sound less chinese, given that ["Alice" is a western name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_%28given_name%29).

The problem is that, likely due to a **bug** in programming such functionality, the placeholder is shown instead the real data when lockscreen is active, or when hanging up an incoming call. Probably by this time the bug has already been fixed, that's why HTC offers *free "repair"* of the phone, as happened to @Siebe.